# Tableview passing same data to another Tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I have a an app that displays players through a Tableview. The user can "add" a new player and input his name, height, weight, picture, etc... and once saved will be added to the Tableview. They can also tap on each player and it takes them to the player detail view controller where it displays all of the information you entered (name, height, weight, throw, bat, position, etc...). This is the current code when a user taps on a player to take them to the player detail page:

```
var player2 = [Player]()

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detail" {
        let playerDetailScreen = segue.destinationViewController as! PlayerDetailViewController

        if let selectedPlayerCell = sender as? PlayerListTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedPlayerCell)!
            let selectedPlayer = player2[indexPath.row]

            playerDetailScreen.playereDetail = selectedPlayer
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to implement a tableview inside the view controller where the user adds a new player and enters the information. This table view is where a user can add the teams or years someone has played (I am using table view because the number of entries can vary). My question is what is the best way to go about this?? Right now I have a 2nd class named Teams.swift for this specific table view but is this the best way to do it? The idea is to then display this data in a  tableview on the detail page (again, because the entries will vary in number) so how do I pass  the data from one tableview to another??

Should I eliminate the [Teams] class and just put it under the [Player] class? Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: It si good to distribute your functionality and not to write messy code in one single ViewController. But it depends on your app flow.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, I would recommend using :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // what happens when user selects a cell
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath.indexPath // This will give you cell that was selected
let selectedPlayer = cell.player  // This gives you the instance of the player (Benefit of using player class)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender : selectedPlayer)

// ^ This will automatically call prepareforseque method.
}
```

**Next**, inside *prepareforsegue* method, do this :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "detail" {
    let playerDetailScreen = segue.destinationViewController as! PlayerDetailViewController

    let selectedPlayer = sender as! Player
    playerDetailScreen.name = self.selectedPlayer.name
    playerDetailScreen.height = self.selectedPlayer.height
    ... so on.
   // So, remember to create property for each name, height, etc. 
   // inside playerDetailScreen
   // This is how you can transfer data


    }

}
```

}

Comment: great, thank you for the advice! In the didSelectRowatIndexPath, for let slectedPlayer = cell.player it says "has no member player" Where did you get cell.player from?

Comment: Hey so, I would recommend that you make a separate class for your cell. In that class make a property Player (instance of player class). This doesnt have to be a UIOutlet, just use it to carry information about the player

Comment: To understand this better, watch this video : "XCode 5 Tutorial Table View Part 1 - Populating The Table - Geeky Lemon Development" on youtube.